# Increment a SqlDataReader field value in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to increment a value from a `SqlDataReader` (SQL Server) to be passed later to a parametrized `INSERT` command (new record).

Is there an easier way on doing this code? It seem so long. Field indexx is bigint (negative value).

First Code:

```
string tmp_index = Sql_DR["indexx"].ToString().Trim();
long temp2_indexx = (Int64.Parse(tmp_index) + 1);
```

Second Code:

```
long temp2_indexx = Int64.Parse(Sql_DR["indexx"].ToString().Trim())+1;
```

What I wanted was something like...

```
long tmp_index = Sql_DR["indexx"] +1;
```

But I get an error:

> Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'int'

I know I can do auto increment on SQL Server itself but this is not the requirement because I'll be replacing the "+ 1" later with a different value (variable).

I've searched already, but the topics I found is not what I wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
long tmp_index = (long)Sql_DR["indexx"] +1;
```

Try the above. You have to cast it to a long since it's by default an object.